# How to start for Single sign-on using identity Server auth2.0 and Authorization?

Tags: identityserver3

I want to use single sign-on for authentication and authorization in multiple website using Identity server. Please, anyone guide me how to proceed for the  implementation Single sign-on using Identity server (Owin/KATANA).

Answer (score 4):

Just having your applications all login to the same Identity Server gives you Single Sign On. SSO comes out of the box.

Implementation Guides:

- [Identity Server with ASP.NET MVC Client](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html)
- [Identity Server with JavaScript Client](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/jsGettingStarted.html)
- [Just Identity Server](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-Standalone-Implementation-Part-1)